# CD Yaml build is triggered for branch in filter, but builds default branch

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have 3 Yaml Pipelines:

- CI1 that should be build on any commit to services/* branches
- CI2 that should be build on any commit to services-release/* branches
- CD that should do the deployment of the artifacts created by CI2

CD is setup the following way:

YAML Settings

[image: YAML Settings]

Triggers Settings

[image: ![Triggers Settings]

As you can see, I've tried different formats of the branches to branch filters. Even if I add non-wildcard filter, I still see the following behavior:

- CD pipeline is triggered after CI2, triggered by commit into services-release/* branch (which is correct), but it releases latest build from a branch, specified in  "default branch for manual and scheduled builds" dropdown - which is develop in my case.

What should I change to deploy the artifact that was generated by CI2 build from services-release/* branch?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the pictures, you are using yaml-pipelines but classic pipeline triggers. While this works for triggering the pipelines, you might want to consider implementing the triggers in yaml files for C1- and C2-pipelines.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers

As for the yaml-based CD pipeline, in order for the pipeline to trigger upon completion of CI2 and for it to download artifacts from the triggering run (instead of latest from the default pipeline), you should reference the CI2-pipeline as resource:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops

So something like:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: ci2_pipeline #this is used to reference this resource in CD pipeline
    source: CI2 #Rename this to match your build pipeline name
    trigger:
      branches:
      - services-release/*
```

For the artifacts, you want to ensure that you are using Pipeline Artifacts instead of classic build artifacts and use the Download Pipeline Artifacts -task in CD-pipeline (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops). So something like:

```
steps:
- download: none # Disable downloading default artifacts
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: "specific"
    project: "$(resources.pipeline.ci2_pipeline.projectID)"
    definition: "$(resources.pipeline.ci2_pipeline.pipelineID)"
    preferTriggeringPipeline: true
        buildVersionToDownload: "latestFromBranch"
    branchName: "$(Build.SourceBranch)"
        targetPath: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)"
```

Comment: Hi JukkaK, thank you for the answer. I did have dowloadPipelineArtifact@2 step, but some properties were different. I've tried to modify it according to your comment and now have to following error Line: 10, Col: 35, Idx: 301) - (Line: 10, Col: 35, Idx: 301): Mapping values are not allowed in this context. ![pipeline screenshot] (https://ibb.co/RbwVmPj)

Comment: That's an error on the yaml formatting, so either there's something wrong with the indentation, or the yaml does not follow the yaml schema (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema). I tried to replicate the same yaml and it works, so I'm wondering if the problem could be on the step where you reference the pipeline resource, and not in the screenshotted area.